# (ASP.NET Cache API) Is it possible that an item may be removed from cache before its set expiry?

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

I've been tasked with implementing server-side cache on a web application to improve performance of the front-end. The objective is to cache a large dataset resulting from an MDX query on an SSAS cube. The cache is to expire at midnight, which is when the cube is processed each day. I've decided to use the Cache.NET API, and so I have this:

```
Cache.Insert("MDXResult", myMDXDataSetThatExpiresAtMidnight, null,
    DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(getMinutesUntilMidnight()), TimeSpan.Zero);
```

What troubles me is something I read on the [MSDN page on ASP.NET Caching: Techniques and Best Practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478965.aspx):

> The simplest way to store data in the Cache is simply to assign it,
>   using a key, just like a HashTable or Dictionary object:
>
> ```
> Cache["key"] = "value";
> ```
>
> This will store the item in the cache without any dependencies, so it
>   will not expire unless the cache engine removes it in order to make
>   room for additional cached data.

The last bit -- the fact that *the cache engine removes cached data in order to make room for additional cached data* -- does it apply to only the case above *where the item is stored in cache without any dependencies*? **How can I be sure that the cache of** `myMDXDataSetThatExpiresAtMidnight` **will not be cleared by the cache engine before its expiry time?**

Alternatively, **is there any way to control the amount of space allocated for server-side cache**, such as a setting in web.config or similar, to ensure that cache isn't inadvertently cleared?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All entries, including those with dependencies, can be removed at any time. The dependencies just help the cache engine calculate when items have expired.

You can not enforce your item to stay in the cache in any way. The cache may remove it for known, unknown and other causes. Usually due to expiration (time or dependency based) or memory pressure. You can, however, use the [Cache.Add overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.add.aspx) which accepts an `CacheItemRemovedCallback onRemoveCallback` which may be a function that calculates a new item (or knows of the old one) and add it again. I'm not sure about the actual timings, but I guess that there is a brief time where the item is not in the cache, while your callback is executed and has not yet added the new item.

You can configure the caching using the [CacheSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.cachesection.aspx) in web.config.